# Are AWS Security Groups configured on the EC2 instance itself or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, port

I recently changed my default ssh port from 22 to *nnnnn*, using **AWS Console - Security Groups**. However, after rebooting the instance I found I couldn't access my instance using:

**ssh -p nnnnn -i $HOME/path_to_my_key.pem ubuntu@elastic_ip_address**

To get it working, I had to revert back to using port 22 in order to access the instance and edit **/etc/sshd_config** to set the port assignment to *nnnnnn*.

My questions are:

(a) At what level does AWS Security Groups control port access? Instance level or network level?

(b) If at the network level, should I also configure an instance level firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security groups are a network feature. They control what ports are open to the instance itself.

Some AMI's also run a software firewall (redhat comes to mind). While somewhat redundant it can provide features that the security group firewall cannot.

The firewall settings only control which ports are open and to who. They do not affect which port each service is listening on. That you have to configure with the service directly.

Comment: Thanks datasage! I am trying to get this question moved to ServerFault as it has been voted 'off-topic' here. I was thinking along the same lines as you, however, this comment from the aws documentation at:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html caused me a little confusion. Yes, it appears to be at the network level with rules applicable to a specific instance.

Answer (score 1):

Security group is not instance level , its just a layer of firewall around your instance .

Comment: Thanks for your response Manjunath.